# How to keep desktop shortcuts in same spot when switching between monitors?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, desktop

When I plug my laptop into different monitors, the desktop shortcuts get messed up. Maybe it's related to the resolution changes. Is there a way to make sure they don't move?

Comment: Do the monitors have different resolutions?

Comment: Yes different resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

There is a freeware software which allows you to save the desktop layout of each resolution.

http://www.softwareok.com/?Download=DesktopOK

The software will be set to German when ran, but you can change this to English or any other language easily by selecting the flag icon on the bottom left.